# <h:outputStylesheet> and relative references

Tags: css, jsf-2

I have a JSF project setup in the typical fashion:

```
myproject
  |-- src/main/webapps
  |    |-- resources
  |    |    |-- css
  |    |    |     |-- 3rdparty.css
  |    |    |      
  |    |    |-- fonts  
  |    |         |    
  |    |         |-- myspecialfont.woff
  |    |
```

And then in my JSF html:

```
 <h:outputStylesheet name="3rdparty.css" library="css"/>
```

This works well, since I can keep the directories consistent if I need to upgrade.

However, in this case, the 3rdparty.css file contains a relative reference:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  src: url('../fonts/myspecialfont.woff');
}
```

As h:outputStylesheet constructs the URI to use `mywebapp/javax.faces.resource/3rdparty.css` this will break the relative references inside it since that path will now refer to `mywebapp/fonts/myspecialfont.woff`.

Is there a good way to keep these locally hosted 3rd party libraries referenced by JSF to handle this kind of relative reference without resorting to manually changing the CSS?

Comment: Try `url(#{request.contextPath}/resources/fonts/my.woff`

Comment: Yes, that would work but I'm trying to avoid editing the 3rd party CSS file to maintain an easy update path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Do not use outputStyleSheet and instead include it directly in your template
2. Modify the CSS file content (as TemarV suggested)

Unfortunately there isn't much else that can be done, because resources are rendered using a different path where-in the library & resource reference are specified as URL parameters instead of being part of the URL.

**Edit:** I would like to highlight a 3rd option as well - writing a custom ResourceHandler. I had to do something on these lines. You can read more about it at -

http://roguexz.blogspot.in/2013/10/jsf-2-returning-resource-url-that-is.html

Comment: I would like to choose #1, but then I lose the ability to determine which CSS files load first because h:outputStylesheet will put anything sourced that way immediately in the head of the document.  My own CSS needs to override some of the classes in 3rdparty.css.  In the meantime, I'm going down path #2 for now.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: If you would like to control the organization of content in the head section, I would suggest that you have a look at how primefaces has implemented the *first* & *last* facets for h:head. Might help you with option 1 as well.

Comment: In case you going to use the option 2, then you can potentially use the shorthand notation #{resource['libraryName:resourceName']} instead of the whole contextPath EL.